# Symfony2 get current authenticated database user credentials

Tags: php, symfony

How I can get authenticated database user credentials?

In my backend I have a section with the credentials of the current user, name, email... how i can get this credentials? it stored in session? how can i get the session user ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the security doc http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object